# Async update child brings deleted parent back

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, asynchronous

I have a simple Spring Boot REST service that implements repository pattern with JPA and Hibernate.

When I delete the Parent entity, if an @Async method is still progressing on its Child entities, the Parent entity is duplicated by the end of @Async method.

Let say I have an Parent entity:

```java
    @Entity
    public class Parent {

       ... // fields like id etc.

       @JsonManagedReference
       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
       @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
       private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();

      ... // getters & setters etc.
    }
```

and Child entity:

```java
    @Entity
    public class Child {

       ... // fields like id etc.

       @JsonBackReference
       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
       @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
       private Parent parent;
      
       ... // getters & setters etc.
      
    }
```

I have an @Async method that updates children periodically (ie run every minute) and I've basic delete method on a @Service class.

```java
    @Async
    public void updateAllChildren() {
        List<Parent> parents = findAll();
        for (Parent parent: parents) {
            ...
            for (Child child : parent.getChildren()) {
                updateChild(child, ...); // <--- time consuming method
            }
        }
    }

    @Async
    public void updateChild(Child child, ...) {
        // do some stuff
        this.childRepository.save(child); // save changes
    }

    public void delete(Parent parent) {
       parent.getChildren().clear();
       this.parentRepository.delete(parent);
    }
```

When a user requests to delete a Parent entity, and if updateAllChildren() method has not been completed yet;

- The parent entity is deleted.
- When children are updated, because the parent entity no longer exists, **clones of parent entity are also created**.

How can I avoid this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't cascade `MERGE` from the child to the parent. Since a merge will create a new entity if one doesn't exist, the deleted entity will be recreated by the cascading merge from the child entity.

Comment: Thank you. Removing cascade is solved the issue.